# How to get last strings starts with '@' and numbers in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I need to extract all whitespace separated "words" at the end of string that either start with the `@` character or that consist solely of digits.

For example, I have this string:

```
hello @tag1 111 world @tag2 @tag3 222 333
```

I need to obtain

```
@tag2 @tag3 222 333
```

I have used this code below:

```
preg_match_all('~\B@\S+|\b\d+\b~', $string, $match);
```

With this, I'll get all strings that started with '@' character and numbers,  even `@tag1` and `111`.

I also tried the code below:

```
$str = 'hello @tag1 111 world @tag2 @tag3 222 333';
$exp = explode(' ', $str);
$arraysfordelete = [];
foreach ($exp as $num => $user) {
    if (!preg_match('~\B@\S+|\b\d+\b~', $user, $match)) {
        array_push($arraysfordelete, $num);
    }
}
$array = array_slice($exp, end($arraysfordelete) + 1);
echo implode(' ', $array);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: [You get 2 matches](https://3v4l.org/VVQuc). What do you need to get in the end?

Comment: i need to get all strings that starts with @ 
example: if list contains 10 tag (like tag1 tag2 tag3 tag4 ...) i need to get all of it
and i need to get all strings that starts with number also
in the same time like 1111 2222 3333 4444 ....

Comment: Just one more thing: do you need match anything in `voice2ip abc@def.com`?

Comment: no
just match with @ and numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [PHP solution](https://3v4l.org/Bag8r) you need:

```php
$str = 'hello @tag1 111 world @tag2 @tag3 222 333';
if (preg_match('~(?<!\S)(@\S+|\d+)(?:\s+(?1))*(?=\s*$)~', $str, $m)) {
    echo $m[0];
}
// => @tag2 @tag3 222 333
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rNOHis/1). *Details*:

- `(?<!\S)` - a location that is either right after a whitespace or start of string
- `(@\S+|\d+)` - Group 1: `@` and one or more non-whitespace chars or one or more digits
- `(?:\s+(?1))*` - zero or more occurrences of one or more whitespaces and then Group 1 pattern
- `(?=\s*$)` - immediately to the right, there must be zero or more whitespaces and end of string.

Answer (score 1):

You could use, for example

```php
~[@\d]\S+~
```

which means match a `@` or a digit, followed by one or more non-space characters `\S+`.

Or

```php
~(?<!\S)[@\d]\S+~
```

if you want to make sure there is no non-space character preceding the `@` or digit.

Comment: why when i using emoji in $tagList its not working?
otherwise its working

Comment: @ebliseblis You need to provide examples of the kind of strings you are searching. Is the emoji appearing right before the start of the tag?

Comment: im searching in all type of strings like english, russian, arabic and emojis
languages tested and was fine but when there is a emoji, not working

the code not working when emoji is right or left of tags or numbers (no difference)

Comment: @ebliseblis When you say "not working", what do you mean? What happens exactly?